# Starting a new Transaction from CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, transactions

How do I start a new transaction when executing some code via the CompletableFuture.runAsync method. For example:

```
void runAsync() {
      ServiceUtils.runAfterTransactionCommits(() -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> 
      doStuff()));
 }

@Transactional
void doStuff() {
    //insert DB update 1
    //insert DB update 2
    throw new RuntimeException("Some error happens");
}
```

The `doStuff` method is not running transactionally because both updates show up in the table even after the exception. How do I start transaction for the async code?

Comment: Have you tried with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`? Or maybe `NESTED`...

Comment: The code which you put would not work neither in synchronous environment. The `doStuff()` needs to be called from the injected bean. If that will help for the async call I'm not sure thought.
What I mean is `@Autowire MyBean bean;` at the Bean class and the call would be run with `bean.doStuff()`.